# How to use .formula with CONCATENATE in vba for a range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to insert the following CONCATENATE equation into a column

```
Range("A2:A" & lRow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE("G2:G"&lRow& ,"_","H2:H"&lRow&,"_","I2:I"&lRow)"
```

I am getting errors (compile error, Expected end of statement) which highlights G2

Answer (score 3):

you do not want a range in the formula itself, just use:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & lRow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(G2,""_"",H2,""_"",I2)"
```

Excel will iterate the relative row numbers correctly.  Also you need to double the quotes around the `_`

Comment: Ahhhh, i had tried that but i forgot the extra "" around the _ .  Thank you!

Comment: @jjpfoot feel free to click the check mark next to the answer to show that the question is closed.